# Conflict with \r\n (new line) between getText and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, gettext, confirm

Could you tell me why this doesn't work (nothing happens) :

```
if (confirm("<?=_("Hello!\r\nContinue?")?>")) {
    alert("Welcome!");
}
```

When this works fine :

```
if (confirm("<?=_("Hello! Continue?")?>")) {
    alert("Welcome!");
}
```

And this too :

```
if (confirm("Hello!\r\nContinue?")) {
    alert("Welcome!");
}
```

GetText is enabled on my server, for info.

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript's String don't allow plain line breaks.
Working example:

```
if (confirm("<?=_("Hello!\\r\\nContinue?")?>")) { // Line breaks escaped
  alert("Welcome!");
}
```

Or:

```
if (confirm("<?=_('Hello!\r\nContinue?')?>")) { // No interpolation
  alert("Welcome!");
}
```

**Disclaimer:** If your translated string contains a line break, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to echo the string out literally into javascript, use a string literal:

```
if (confirm("<?=_('Hello!\r\nContinue?')?>")) {
    alert("Welcome!");
}
```

Note the apostrophes surrounding the PHP string. This will echo out '\r\n' AS '\r\n' rather than chr(13) chr(10).

I'm not entirely sure how this will work in your GetText .PO file though with regards to indexing the original 'Hello!\r\nContinue?' - I'm guessing that it'll be in there as `Hello!\r\nContinue?`, a string that's available for translation, I'm not sure what would happen if you had another GetText index of:

```
Hello!
Continue?
```

(with the actual CRLF between the words)

Basically, I'm not sure how GetText copes with strings, as literals or not.